# Linking problem in dynamic library while mixing C C++ code

Tags: c++, c, gcc, dylib

I had a C dynamic library, due to some requirement change I have to do some refactoring.

I had following code in one c file.

```
__attribute__((noinline))
static void *find_document(...)
{
  ...
}

bool docuemnt_found(const char *name) {
 ...
    find_document(...);
 ...
}
```

I separated the docuemnt_found() function in different cpp file. Now docuemnt_found() function cannot link to find_document() method?

I tried creating header for the c file and then include header using `extern "C"` but it did not work.

I want to keep find_document() inline. Is there anything missing here or something wrong?

Comment: Check out the meaning of `static` for function declarations. Then remove the word `static`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is the declaration of the function as `static` - in C, this says that it should be available to other functions within the same compilation unit (.c file), but not to other functions outside the file.  Removing `static` should solve the problem.

Incidentally, the second function is misspelled - it should be `document_found`, not `docuemnt_found`.

Comment: yah! Sorry about the typo. Thank you.